# Mapbox webservice: Change format of tiles from PNG to JPG

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Does anyone know how to set down the quality of Mapbox tiles using the JS API?

```
this.map = L.mapbox.map("map", this.mapID, {
    // pass in format here?,
    zoomControl: false,
    tileLayer: {
        continuousWorld: true,
        noWrap: false
    }
});
```

https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/maps/#format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Image format of the tiles is specified on the TileLayer instance:

```
var map = L.mapbox.map('map');
var layer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('examples.map-zr0njcqy', {
    format: 'jpg70'
});
map.addLayer(layer).setView([0, 0], 2);
```

The available formats are:

```
    'png', 'jpg',

    // PNG
    'png32', 'png64', 'png128', 'png256',

    // JPG
    'jpg70', 'jpg80', 'jpg90'
```